# Avoid CPU pegging on Spark Standalone

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a daily pipeline running on Spark Standalone 2.1. Its deployed in and runs on AWS EC2 and uses S3 for its persistence layer. For the most part, the pipeline runs without a hitch, but occasionally the job hangs on a single worker node during a `reduceByKey` operation. When I work into the worker, I notice that the CPU (as seen via top) is pegged at 100%. My remedy so far is to reboot the worker node so that Spark re-assigns the task and the job proceeds fine from there.

I would like to be able to mitigate this issue. I gather that I can prevent CPU pegging by switching to use YARN as my cluster manager, but I wonder whether I could configure Spark Standalone to prevent CPU pegging by maybe limiting the number of cores that get assigned to the Spark job ? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.